# how to get offline mode working for an android application

Tags: android, caching, media, offline-mode

In my android application am actually letting users to stream music .I want to add offline functionality and i want the synced files can be only played using my application not directly accessible by device owner my first idea was to use an sqlite database but it would be too heavy for my app
I heard about LruCache but i don't know if it is possible to stock mp3 file in LruCache and if the cached files using Lrucache aren't accessible in rooted phones?

Is there any other way?
And what is the most common way to enable offline mode in android applications

Comment: How about saving it to a temporary folder and deleting it when you want?

Comment: it is possible but i wonder if the device is rooted is it possible for the user to access the mp3 files(My mp3 files collection is very rare and i don't want that someones steals it)

Comment: This answer says that you can save it to internal memory of your app and avoid users with non-rooted phones to access them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13406595/1152444

Comment: you could always store those files but encode and decode them as you want and in that way even if they found the files it would not be easy to load use them